# django query running forever and not timing out

Tags: mysql, python, django, gunicorn

I have some django applications that is killing my mysql server
there are queries that are running and not timing out and clogging my mysql server

Just need help on how to resolve this issue the proper way
not sure if this is how django is designed or i need to add a timeout settings
i thought django should do this by default, not sure because makes zero sense to have this with no timeout

Here are the queries that are not timing out or closing

```
MySQL on localhost (5.7.19)                                                                                                                                                                                     load 5.27 4.81 4.69 4/2383 41852 up 0+00:18:41 [19:13:16]
 Queries: 8.6k     qps:    8 Slow:     0.0         Se/In/Up/De(%):    61/01/02/00
 Sorts:      0 qps now:    5 Slow qps: 0.0  Threads:   99 (  99/   1) 44/00/00/00
 Key Efficiency: 98.9%  Bps in/out: 839.8/22.3k   Now in/out: 566.3/22.5k

       Id      User         Host/IP         DB       Time    Cmd    State Query
       --      ----         -------         --       ----    ---    ----- ----------
        6 webapp_user       localhost webapp_db       1096  Query  Sending SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2017-09-19 18:44:56'
        9 webapp_user       localhost webapp_db       1086  Query  Sending SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2017-09-19 18:45:09'
       11 webapp_user       localhost webapp_db       1085  Query  Sending SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2017-09-19 18:45:10'
       15 webapp_user       localhost webapp_db       1067  Query  Sending SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2017-09-19 18:45:28'
       16 webapp_user       localhost webapp_db       1056  Query  Sending SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2017-09-19 18:45:39'
       20 webapp_user       localhost webapp_db       1053  Query  Sending SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2017-09-19 18:45:42'
       25 webapp_user       localhost webapp_db       1037  Query  Sending SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2017-09-19 18:45:58'
       28 webapp_user       localhost webapp_db       1025  Query  Sending SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2017-09-19 18:46:11'
       29 webapp_user       localhost webapp_db       1022  Query  Sending SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2017-09-19 18:46:14'
       32 webapp_user       localhost webapp_db       1006  Query  Sending SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2017-09-19 18:46:29'
       35 webapp_user       localhost webapp_db        994  Query  Sending SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2017-09-19 18:46:42'
       36 webapp_user       localhost webapp_db        990  Query  Sending SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2017-09-19 18:46:45'
```

This is just a copy of what i currently have, those queries keeps on running for a long time and till i restart mysql server and they start again and keep running and eventually they clog up cpu and i/o on the server

Below are some of the content in `settings.py` file

```
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 60*60*24*365*5 
SESSION_ENGINE = 'webapp.sessions.backends.db' 
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True


# 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
'webapp.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
# 'django.contrib.sessions', 
'sessions',
```

What do i do to fix this?

Thanks

UPDATE:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE django_session;
+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table          | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| django_session | CREATE TABLE `django_session` (
  `session_key` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `session_data` longtext NOT NULL,
  `expire_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_login` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_key`),
  KEY `django_session_c25c2c28` (`expire_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)




mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM django_session;
+----------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table          | Non_unique | Key_name                | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| django_session |          0 | PRIMARY                 |            1 | session_key | A         |    24152280 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| django_session |          1 | django_session_c25c2c28 |            1 | expire_date | A         |    20456614 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+----------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

i added

`wait_timeout = 120`

but still experiencing same issue

Answer (score 0):

wait_timeout plays a large part in allowing long run times.  Check the documentation for your version of MySQL.

Comment: am using mysql 5.7

Comment: so what do i do? still need help

Comment: Post the results of  SHOW CREATE TABLE Django_session  AND  results of  SHOW INDEX FROM Django_session.  DECIDE how many seconds you will tolerate this 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...... and in your my.ini/.cnf within [mysqld] section ADD a line 
WAIT_TIME = nnnnn     # seconds before connection termination by MySQL.  Shutdown/restart MySQL.

Comment: adding `wait_timeout = 120` did not solve my problem..also i posted the output of the commands in question above

Comment: TALK with your software supplier is the most expedient way of stabilizing your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Change your
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2017-09-19 18:44:56' 
      TO THIS 
        SELECT COUNT(`last_login`) FROM `django_session` WHERE `django_session`.`last_login` >= '2017-09-19 18:44:56'

Comment: where do i change this? what file or what location?

Comment: Check with your software supplier, please.

Comment: I use django and mysql..the app was made about 5 years ago...dont have access to the developer anymore...where can i edit the query you mentioned?

Comment: If the absence of any form of support talent, my suggestion would be to start with web search for Django tutorial and go from there.  My focus is on MySQL and it's many flavors NGINX, MARIADB and others in the tuning of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES and related information.  Good Luck.